# Coredata chained Relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2, relationship

What is the best way to update or add data if `relationships` are chained.

I have my `coredata` designed like this:

[image: Relationship]

I have 3 Entities

> 1) **User** `To_Many` **Category**
>
> 2) **Category** `To_Many` **Item**
>
> 3) **Item** `To_One` **Category**

`User` is required before adding a `Category`, and `Category` is required before adding an `Item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Just set the to-one relationship, the corresponding inverse relationship will be set automatically by Core Data.

```
newItem.category = category
category.user = user
```

*According to best practice, I am renaming the clumsy attribute names    `itemCategory`, `categoryUser`, `categoryInUser` to simply `category`, `user`,  `categories` respectively.*